# Why is my css applying only half of the div

Tags: html, css

Why is half of my css code working only on half of the div?
this is my code

```css
#cardleft h1{
  margin-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
}

#cardleft{
  border: 2px solid #68C3A3;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px 0px 0px 30px ;
  color: #4aa0c2 !important;
}
  
#cardleft:hover{
  background-color: #4eb28f;
  color: gold !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="cardleft" class="col-md-4 ">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-6x"></i>  
  </div>
  <h1>LinkedIn</h1>
</div>
```

I tried multiple ways on doing this, I still am getting same issues. 
tried adding `!important` but nothing seems to change.

but weirdly enough the same code works in codepen.io

am I doing something wrong in the IDE? I'm using visual studio code

Comment: Please explain by "half of the div". Also, share a minimal, concrete and verifiable example.

Comment: only the icon changes color when mouse is hovering the div. but not the text.

Comment: If this is bootstrap, you need to tag it as such as it changes the question.

Comment: can you please explain? new to this and don't really understand what you mean

Comment: Works in the snippet.

Comment: @Grumpy my point exactly, at codepen.io it also works, but somehow in my IDE is not, I tried restarting it, restarting my laptop too, but st ill the same thing

Comment: Maybe you are using a crappy IDE

Comment: Maybe another div is overlapping. But there is no issue with your code.

Comment: You don't need the `!important` in your code. Delete it

Comment: does your IDE publishes the result after each save? sometimes IDEs offers you a working set and a published copy you can see the result

Comment: @lupz its microsoft visual studio code, I've been told its the best out there. at least for free.

Comment: @JarlikStepsto after changes, I usually save the file and reload the page. and if no changes are made I force refresh the page, clearing cookies and cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#cardleft h1{
  margin-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
}
#cardleft h1, #cardleft i{
  color: #4aa0c2;
}
#cardleft{
  border: 2px solid #68C3A3;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px 0px 0px 30px ;
}
  
#cardleft:hover{
  background-color: #4eb28f;
}

#cardleft:hover h1, #cardleft:hover i{
  color: gold !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="cardleft" class="col-md-4 ">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-6x"></i>  
  </div>
  <h1>LinkedIn</h1>
</div>
```

You need to add color style to `h1` tag.

Comment: You are changing font color of the div which is wrapper of h1 tag and at the same time, Bootstap target the h1 tag, that's why changing color on hover is not working. You need to change color of <h1> tag on hover

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you just have to create unique names for the css classes in this HTML file? Sounds like the text color is being overwritten somewhere else because of class names.